# The xcolor package can't find the color "turquoise"?

Tags: color

[Based on this link](http://www.maths.adelaide.edu.au/anthony.roberts/LaTeX/ltxusecol.php) the color "Turquoise" should be a part of the xcolor package. I keep getting the error:

> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `turquoise'.

Here's my simple file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\color{turquoise}
Turquoise text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's `Turquoise`, with a capital `T`.

Comment: .... I could have sworn I tried that, yet it still gave me an error but now it works... Guess I need to get some sleep. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have 3 more variants with `svgnames`, and 8 with `x11names`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was only a typo, solved in comment.